How do I calculate the L3 cache miss rate and find number of trips to main memory using perf?
I'm trying to measure the L3 cache miss rate using the following formula:

I found that LLC misses can be obtained using this perf command from How to catch the L3-cache hits and misses by perf tool in Linux:
perf stat -e r412e <command>

However, I'm having trouble finding the event that corresponds to LLC accesses (LLC references). Does perf support this event? If so, could someone point me in the right direction?
Additionally, I'm profiling the number of trips to main memory. From my understanding, if we miss all levels of cache, the system accesses main memory to fetch the data. Should I be tracking LLC cache misses, or would cache references be the correct metric?
Any help identifying the correct perf events for both LLC references and trips to main memory would be greatly appreciated.

What model of CPU? The available HW counters depend on the microarchitecture.  (e.g. Intel vs. AMD vs. ARM Cortex-A...)

In terms of generic events, LLC-loads and LLC-load-misses will give you the miss rate for demand loads.  That might or might not cover read-for-ownership loads from stores that miss in L1d, I haven't investigated.  (Note that on some uarches, the last-level cache is only L2 if they don't have an L3, hence the generic event just being LLC.)

I'm using Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-14900K currently. And do you mean LLC load misses / LLC loads will give the LLC demand miss rate?

Yes, that's what perf stat will calculate for you and show in the right-hand column if you enable both events for one run, e.g. with perf stat -d or with -e cycles,instructions,...

Thanks. Any idea about the knob to find number of trips to main memory?

perf list on my Skylake includes events like offcore_requests.l3_miss_demand_data_rd, offcore_response.demand_code_rd.l3_miss.any_snoop / offcore_response.demand_code_rd.l3_miss_local_dram.any_snoop (local vs. remote DRAM being relevant for multi-socket servers only, but client chips use the same microarchitecture), and offcore_response.demand_rfo.l3_miss.any_snoop (RFO being Read For Ownership on a cache-miss store).  There's also TMA stuff like tma_info_system_dram_bw_use.  I don't know which of these are most useful, they all seem overly specific to just overall DRAM accesses.

I see the events like this on my intel system:
cpu_core:
L1-icache-load-misses OR cpu_core/L1-icache-load-misses/
cpu_atom:
L1-dcache-loads OR cpu_atom/L1-dcache-loads/
Do you know what is the difference between CPU core an CPU atom which one is teh accurate metric?

Your CPU is a hybrid with P-core and E-cores.  The E-core microarchitecture's ancestry is in Silvermont Atom, so IIRC the cpu_atom events are for efficiency cores.  The performance cores are Sandybridge-family, so their ancestry is in the Intel Core branding, thus cpu_core is probably specific to P-cores.  Oh, the man page explains this: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-stat.1.html#INTEL_HYBRID_SUPPORT
